# Using mvn clean install from cmd, while running the app from intellij its seems like it rebuilding it

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm trying to automate some mvn commands to set up the dev env in IntelliJ.

I'm running from cmd:

```
   mvn clean install -DskipTests -P profile1,profile2
```

When it finish, I'm running the app from IntelliJ, it seems like IntelliJ is compelling and building it again before it runs.

Is there a way to add flags to the cmd command in order to save the step of IntelliJ compiling & building it?

Comment: When _running the app from IntelliJ_, do you have a run configuration and removed the build pre-action?

Comment: Why do you compile externally and then running from IDEA ... furthermore you can run the apps from within IDEA ... why do you need profiles to build ?